# expected reference but got (raw string) @+android:style/Animation.Translucent

Tags: android, linux, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

when I update the as version from 2.3 to 3.0 and compile the same project,there are some errors.How to solve the problem?thks.

```
AGPBI:{
"kind":"error",
"text":"error: expected reference but got (raw string) @+android:style/Animation.Translucent.",
"sources":[
  {
     "file":"/home/.../android/.../app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml",
     "position":{
        "startLine":533
     }
  }
  ],
  "original":"",
  "tool":"AAPT"
  }AGPBI:{
  "kind":"error",
  "text":"error: expected reference but got (raw string) @+android:style/Animation.Translucent.",
  "sources":[
  {
     "file":"/home/.../android/.../app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-zh-rCN/values-zh-rCN.xml",
     "position":{
        "startLine":165
     }
  }
  ],
  "original":"",
  "tool":"AAPT"
  }
```

the new log looks like this 
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar] Warning:The android.dexOptions.incremental property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process. /home/.../app/src/main/res/values/dcloud_styles.xml Error:(3, 5) error: expected reference but got (raw string) @+android:style/Animation.Translucent. /home/.../app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml Error:(534) expected reference but got (raw string) @+android:style/Animation.Translucent. /home/.../app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-zh-rCN/values-zh-rCN.xml Error:(166) error: expected reference but got (raw string) @+android:style/Animation.Translucent. Error:(166) expected reference but got (raw string) @+android:style/Animation.Translucent. Error:failed linking references. Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

```
Failed to execute aapt Information:BUILD FAILED in 2s Information:9 errors Information:1 warning Information:See complete output in console
```

here is the xml file.


    
        @anim/dcloud_slide_in_from_top
        @anim/dcloud_slide_out_to_top

```
<style name="dcloud_defalut_dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/image_pick_title_btn_normal</item> 
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">top</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> -->
</style>
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>


 <style name="ActionSheetStyleIOS6">
    <item name="actionSheetBackground">@drawable/as_bg_ios6</item>
    <item name="cancelButtonBackground">@drawable/as_cancel_bt_bg</item>
    <item name="otherButtonTopBackground">@drawable/as_other_bt_bg</item>
    <item name="otherButtonMiddleBackground">@drawable/as_other_bt_bg</item>
    <item name="otherButtonBottomBackground">@drawable/as_other_bt_bg</item>
    <item name="otherButtonSingleBackground">@drawable/as_other_bt_bg</item>
    <item name="cancelButtonTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="otherButtonTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="actionSheetPadding">20dp</item>
    <item name="otherButtonSpacing">5dp</item>
    <item name="cancelButtonMarginTop">20dp</item>
    <item name="actionSheetTextSize">16sp</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionSheetStyleIOS7">
    <item name="actionSheetBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="cancelButtonBackground">@drawable/slt_as_ios7_cancel_bt</item>
    <item name="otherButtonTopBackground">@drawable/slt_as_ios7_other_bt_top</item>
    <item name="otherButtonTitleBackground">@drawable/slt_as_ios7_other_bt_title</item>
    <item name="otherButtonMiddleBackground">@drawable/slt_as_ios7_other_bt_middle</item>
    <item name="otherButtonBottomBackground">@drawable/slt_as_ios7_other_bt_bottom</item>
    <item name="otherButtonSingleBackground">@drawable/slt_as_ios7_other_bt_single</item>
    <item name="cancelButtonTextColor">#1E82FF</item>
    <item name="otherButtonTextColor">#1E82FF</item>
    <item name="destructiveButtonTextColor">#E8484A</item>
    <item name="titleButtonTextColor">#8C8C8C</item>
    <item name="actionSheetPadding">10dp</item>
    <item name="otherButtonSpacing">0dp</item>
    <item name="cancelButtonMarginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="actionSheetTextSize">16sp</item>
</style>
    <style name="featureLossDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/image_pick_title_btn_normal</item> 
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
</style>

 <color name="image_pick_title_btn_pressed">#f4f4f4</color>
 <color name="image_pick_title_btn_normal">#00000000</color>
 <color name="ime_background">#cccccc</color>

 <declare-styleable name="ActionSheets">
    <attr name="actionSheetStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="ActionSheet">
    <attr name="actionSheetBackground" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="cancelButtonBackground" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="otherButtonTopBackground" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="otherButtonTitleBackground" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="otherButtonMiddleBackground" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="otherButtonBottomBackground" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="otherButtonSingleBackground" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="cancelButtonTextColor" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="otherButtonTextColor" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="destructiveButtonTextColor" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="titleButtonTextColor" format="color|reference" />
    <attr name="actionSheetPadding" format="dimension|reference" />
    <attr name="otherButtonSpacing" format="dimension|reference" />
    <attr name="cancelButtonMarginTop" format="dimension|reference" />
    <attr name="actionSheetTextSize" format="dimension|reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: What are lines 533 of values.xml and line 165 of values.zh.rCN.xml? I'm fairly sure there's `@+android` there that should be `@android`

Comment: do you have some idea for solving the problem?thks.

Comment: If you have things to add, you should edit your question rather than post the additions as answers.

Comment: I see the values.xml you posted isn't 533 lines long, is the file `app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml` still present? Can you find the offending line in there?

Comment: @Heikki Mäenpää,the problem has been solved.Delete the + is OK.thks.

Comment: Please put the solution you found in an answer so it's easier to refer to.

Answer (score 3):

"@+android:style/Animation.Translucent" is an incorrect reference to a style, it should be "@android:style/Animation.Translucent".